# Parse.com data migration

Tags: parse-platform

I am developing an application that needs a backend, so I choose parse because I do not have the capacity to write a truly great backend myself.

Now I want to migrate my data from parse to my own system, because parse.com is owned by facebook (privacy concerns, etc), and because it is shutting down. Does parse provide a way to efficiently do that?

**EDIT**

[Parse announces Shutdown of Services.](http://blog.parse.com/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonv6rPZKXonjHpfsX64uwrUa%2B1lMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ARMNiI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTbHGMblmy7gNUxU%3D)

Best practices and options for migrating from Parse to ? AWS, or other system, vs creating new backend based on parse.com code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shouldn't be difficult at all if your own backend can handle an upload of a JSON file.
Parse allows you export your data in a JSON formatted file.

All you have to do is go to the "Settings" tab in your Parse Dashboard - then click the "Export Data" tab. This will then give you a URL for you to retrieve the .zip of this JSON file.

You will then just have to import your data to your new backend.

Comment: If you look into Document store databases like Couchbase and Couchbase Mobile, those are great alternatives where the key-value JSON format of your data would be intact to migrate over easily.

The server backend is also open source and free to install/host on any provider too.

Comment: I tried the migrate tool and it works. But I have another problem. I have photo on Parse backend. After migrating, photo column is changed to url (string). If my app point to new backend, photo could not be loaded. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you move your data from Parse to another location i.e. Mongo or another PaaS provider, you will still need to update the client code. If you have a mobile app, and your end users don't bother to update their app, then how do they connect to the new datasource (DB)?

You would need to build this migrate functionality into your client from the 1st public version to be sure to capture all users, so you can flip the switch. That's a lot of work, you have to write your own wrapper for the Parse API or REST calls.

If your app is serving HTML from the server i.e. a PhoneGap app, with server side page rendering, then you are de-coupled from the app executable on the end users phone/tablet. MeteorJS has hot code push to solve this.

But trying to migrate data without having a plan in place from the get go is pretty much horrible. You could send a notification to all the old clients that need to update their mobile app, telling them to update, and shutting down the Parse backend, but that's not a great user experience. If they don't have notifications turned ON... You could code an alert/msg to popup based on you populating a field in the parse DB, poll to check it every few mins. Still not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You mobile client code would need to updated accordingly.  I wrote up a part 1 of a [blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/migration-from-parse-to-couchbase) on these considerations for migrating over from Parse to Couchbase Mobile stack and the reasons why.

Overall there will be some work to do as you would need to either copy over the entire datebase and then let the user to update their client app when appropriate to attach to the new backend.  Getting everyone on the new system is required now as Parse is shutting down so a consideration is to create a requirement product feature with a new version number for upgrade.